# Not working IEEE 802.3af PoE-PD Interface Controller (NCP1091)

Tags: pcb-design, circuit-design, grounding, ethernet, poe

For a hobby project, I am developing a PoE-powered PCB. At the moment, I have the following schematic and pcb layout designed.

[image]

[image]

[image: Poe interface controller pcb layout]

When testing the PCB, I just can't get the PoE to work. My Switch (netgear GS308EP) does not acknowledge my PCB as a PoE device. I have already tried several things namely:

1. placing a 100nF capacitor in series between RXCT and TXCT with R40 and R41. This caused my switch to acknowledge the PCB, because the PoE status LED started blinking (1 sec on and 2 sec off). When I looked with the osciloscope at the output of IC9 (ETH_+ and ETH_-) I saw a pulse with a voltage of 52V.
2. my next thought was that IC9 was drawing too much current from the switch. So I adjusted the inrush resistor to 300 kOhm and later to 90 kOhm. Unfortunately, I could not find a calculation on how to calculate this resistor. Does anyone know this calculation? Unfortunately, this adjustment gave the same problem.
3. Tried all types of resistance classes, namely: 4420, 953, 549, 357, 255 Ohm. Still the same problem.
4. Removed R26 and R33 and connected the UVLO pin to VPORTN for the internal setting.
5. Diode bridge replaced for loose 1n4004 diodes.
6. Disconnected C49.

Do you guys have any idea what could be wrong with the schematic or pcb layout?

Comment: Are you taking enough current from the switch? If you don't take at least 5 to 10mA it will switch off power after 400ms.

Comment: You also have 150 Ohms across each of the power pairs (though the 100nF capacitor has now removed it from one of them). That's 11W at 42V.

Comment: That's only showing the RJ45 connections and PoE controller. Where's the power supply that takes in power from PoE controller output? And yes, so far your all four terminating resistors prevent applying of PoE as they would go up with a puff of smoke if there were supply on either the data pairs or the unused pair. Also, is this product isolated or does it have any parts like external connections to other devices, or can user touch any voltages present on board?

Comment: @Finbarr That was it! I temporarily removed the 150 ohm resistors and hung a resistor on the output to request a current of 20mA. The switch now gives a constant voltage of 53V. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Justme The Poe controller is connected to two DC/DC converters (SiC464). The PCB is connected to several sensors. The user can't touch any voltages. Will my layout or schedule cause problems with this?

Comment: If there were any connections available on the other side of the ethernet transformers you'd need to use isolated DC/DC converters and make sure nothing connected the two sides.

Comment: @NeDor I don't know as you don't show the schematics. Either you need islolated DC/DC converters or not. Do you have isolated DC/DC converters?